# Помогите добавить в мой код Глобальных переменных

Tags: python, api, github, переменные

Код:

```
# coding=utf-8
from SimpleQIWI import *
from SimpleQIWI import QApi

token = input ( 'Токен: ' )
phone = input ( 'Номер кошелька: ' )
api = QApi ( token = token , phone = phone )  # type: QApi

print('Выберите функцию: ')
print('[1] - Баланс счета')
print('[2] - Вывод денег')
vvod = input ( "" )  # type: str


def info ( ) :
    # type: () -> object
    """

    :rtype: object
    """
    print('Кошелек найден!')


print('Баланс клиента с номером' , phone , 'равен: ' , api.balance)


# noinspection PyGlobalUndefined
def vanish():
    # type: () -> object
    """
    :rtype: object
    """
    global num
    summ == input('Введите сумму: ')
    num == input('Номер кошелька: ')

try:
 api.pay ( account = str (num) , amount = int (summ) , comment = ' ' )
 print('Баланс клиента с номером' , phone , 'равен: ' , api.balance)
except QIWIAPIError:
 print('Невозможно осуществить платеж самому себе')
print (':D')

if vvod == "1":
 info()
elif vvod == "2":
 vanish()
else:
 quit
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Баланс клиента с номером  равен:  [4.72, 0.0]
  File "/Users/timofeysoroka/Desktop/Progr/venv/1111.py", line 38, in <module>
    api.pay ( account = str (num) , amount = int (summ) , comment = ' ' )
NameError: name 'num' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Как я понял, необходимо добавить глобальную переменную

```
global num
```

или

```
global summ
```

Не помогает

Comment: Операторы присваивания `=` и сравнения `==` не путаете?

Comment: Могу путать ибо максимально плохо в этом всем разбираюсь, главное исправить код

Answer (score 0):

Нужно исправить функцию `vanish`

Глобальными должны быть обе переменные, и, конечно заменить оператор сравнения на присваивание

```
def vanish():
    global num, summ
    summ = input('Введите сумму: ')
    num = input('Номер кошелька: ')
```

Comment: Исправил функцию "vanish" как Вы сказали, Теперь Выдаёт ошибку в "try:"  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/timofeysoroka/Desktop/Progr/venv/1111.py", line 38, in <module>
    api.pay ( account = str (num) , amount = int (summ) , comment = ' ' )
NameError: name 'num' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: При выводе баланса? Все правильно - в этом случае функция vanish не запускается и не определяет эти переменные. Откуда в этом случае должны эти данные браться?